# Android emulator requires hardware acceleration

Tags: android, android-emulator

I got this error in my emulator

```
Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!

Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will address this in a future release.

Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have tried few things to solve this firstly its not working in lower API. I tried it on API 15.
Secondly, HAXM is properly installed
I checked that

Comment: processor and motherboard model?

Answer (score 0):

try to add to Android Manifest this line

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true"> 
    <activity ... />
</application>
```

You can read about it: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel